# Azure DataFactory V2 - Salesforce Linkedservice with OAuth token

Tags: oauth, salesforce, azure-data-factory

I am looking to connect to salesforce in ADF v2 using OAuth rather than username, password, secret.

Does anyone have any ideas how to do this? Or alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

Oauth isn’t supported.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-salesforce#linked-service-properties

Maybe you could write your own
Code and then call ADF custom activity?

Comment: Yes, i wanted to avoid writing custom code but it would seem for now its the only option.